# Как инкрементировать имя экземпляра при его создании c#?

Tags: c#

Есть такой код:

```
public static int count = 0;

public void CreateNewChoco()
{
    Chocolate choco = new Chocolate();
}
```

Как сделать так, что б при создании нового экземпляра класса Chocolate имя этого экземпляра становилось "
choco" + инкрементированный count.

Тоесть если два раза запустить эту функцию то создасться два экземпляра с именами "choco0" и "choco1".

Comment: Имя _переменной_ в рантайме задать/изменить невозможно.

Answer (score 4):

Вариантов 2 - или создать статическую переменную-счетчик которую нужно дергать при каждой инициализации и создавать имя.

1.

```
public class Choko {
    private static int _count = 0;

    public string Name;

    public void Choko()
    {
        Name = $"choko{count++}"
    }
}
```

2. Или же паттерн "фабрика". Где фабрика генерит имя каждому следующему итему.